# How to get rid of gridlines in all the subplots of scatter_matrix in plotly?

Tags: plotly, gridlines, scatter-matrix

I am trying to get rid of the gridlines in all the subplots of the scatter_matrix plot. I have set the showgrid parameter to False for the x-axis and y-axis, but the majority of the subplots do have the gridlines still being presented. How do I resolve this issue?

This is my code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter_matrix(df,
    dimensions=["sepal_width", "sepal_length", "petal_width", "petal_length"],
    color="species")
fig.for_each_xaxis(lambda x: x.update(showgrid=False))
fig.for_each_yaxis(lambda x: x.update(showgrid=False))
fig.show()
```

This is the image:
[image: ploy]

Answer (score 0):

- the axes are not already in the **layout** hence reason the approach you have used does not work.  Also `update_xaxes()` and `update_yaxes()` do not work
- using a **dict** comprehension to explicitly set for 10 x&y axes does work

```
fig.update_layout(
    {
        f"{ax}axis{n+1 if n>0 else ''}": {"showgrid": False}
        for n, ax in itertools.product(range(10), list("xy"))
    }
)
```

[image]